# How do I pass the this element to the result of getJSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to do the following...

```
$('.showcomments').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().hide();
  jQuery.getJSON('comments.json', function($data) {
    $(this).parent().append($data['value'])
    //this is meant to be the instance of 
    //$('.showcomments') that has been clicked
  });
});
```

the problem is that the callback of getJSON of course did not inherit the this item... but how do I do what I am intending?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reference it in a variable:

```
$('.showcomments').click(function()
{
    var $th = $(this);   // References the clicked .showcomments
    $th.parent().hide();
    jQuery.getJSON('comments.json',function($data)
    {
        $th.parent().append($data['value']); // will reference the correct element
    });
});
```

Comment: My thoughts exactly.  Within the callback function of an AJAX request `this` is a reference to the request.